# How to remove"simatic shell" from my pc?

Tags: windows-10

I uninstalled wincc but this folder is not being removed. How can I get rid of this folder?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

Look for a folder that contains "simatic shell" and delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to get rid of this. Go to Control Panel -> Devices and Printers -> Right Click your PC -> Properties. The rest is explained in the attached image. Now windows will allow you to delete this folder. At the end, delete the simatic shell folder from My PC.

[image: device properties]

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: and what is that?

Answer (score 1):

I just searched for "simatic shell" in registry and removed all keys/fields with it

it's gone now

Answer (score 1):

Press Win+R, type `regedit`, enter the registry editor, and follow the below instructions.

1. Press Ctrl+F.
2. Type "a0953c92" and press Enter.
3. Delete the "a9053c92" registry.
4. Then after delete the below of the "3dfdf296" registry which is different from a9053c92.
5. Check your Windows File Explorer, simatic shell is gone.

   [image: [1]]

Comment: If you could screenshot that instead of taking a photo to that, the quality would increase a ton.